# Visual Basic: Making multiple forms for an order

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've been working on this project for two weeks now and I'm drained from all the hiccups I've come across. Now I've hit a brick wall.

I'm making a "simple" order form in Visual Basic 2010 that calculates the amount due for an order and then from the total determines what the shipping will be. I've been able to accomplish the following tasks:

1. accept customer data (name, address, city, state abbreviation, zipcode)
2. calculate total with shipping costs (accurately, for the most part)
3. clear the order form and exit

But the way I have it right now, a customer can only put in 1 order form.

**Problem:** I have to figure out a way to allow a customer to place an **order form for multiple items.** (I'll assume that a customer will not place an order for more than 20 items). So what would be the best way to go about saving the information for multiple items then calculating the cost at the end?

If it's multiple form creation, how is that done? Is the keyword "Container" the way to go, and how? At the end of the day, I just don't know how to create this multiple item form (it's like a database in Visual Basic), so any method, at least pointing me in the right direction, would be helpful.

(Tried to post an image of my work so far but I'm new here - can't post images yet. I've posted a bit of my code below - code works for 1 order)

Snippet Code:

```
Private Sub total_mouseleave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles total.MouseLeave

  Dim gs_1 As Decimal = 4.95
  Dim gs_2 As Decimal = 6.95
  Dim gs_3 As Decimal = 8.95
  Dim gs_4 As Decimal = 10.95
  Dim gs_5 As Decimal = 12.95
  Dim ex_1 As Decimal = 14.95
  Dim ex_2 As Decimal = 16.95
  Dim ex_3 As Decimal = 18.95
  Dim ex_4 As Decimal = 20.95
  Dim ex_5 As Decimal = 22.95
  Dim totalcost As Decimal

  totalcost = Convert.ToDecimal(total.Text)

  If gs_radiobutton.Checked Then
    If (totalcost < 1) Then
      total.Text = Val(0)
      shipping.Text = Val(0)
    ElseIf (1 < totalcost AndAlso totalcost < 15) Then
      total.Text = Val(totalcost + gs_1)
      shipping.Text = ground_1
    ElseIf (15 < totalcost AndAlso totalcost <= 49.99) Then
      total.Text = totalcost + gs_2
      shipping.Text = gs_2
    ElseIf (50 < totalcost AndAlso totalcost <= 99.99) Then
      total.Text = totalcost + g_3
      shipping.Text = gs_3
    ElseIf (100 < totalcost AndAlso totalcost <= 199.99) Then
      total.Text = totalcost + gs_4
      shipping.Text = gs_4
    Else
      total.Text = totalcost + gs_5
      shipping.Text = gs_5
    End If
  End If

  '// . . . . 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your post if you mean order forms as in a Form object within VB or an order placed by the user.

If you meant orders placed by the user then it would be simpler to use a single form but create a few custom classes to hold all the order line details:

```
' Class used for each order line
Public Class orderline

   Public Value As Decimal
   Public StockID As Integer
   Public Qty As Integer

End Class

' Class used to store the entire order
Public Class Order

   ' List of orderlines (similar to an array)
   Public OrderLines As List(Of orderline)

   Private _totalcost As Decimal

   Public ReadOnly Property TotalCost As Decimal

       Get
           Dim t As Decimal

           For Each l In OrderLines
               t = t + (l.Value * l.Qty)
           Next

           Return t

       End Get

   End Property

End Class
```

Then in the form you can use the classes as below:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim ord1 As New Order

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        TextBox1.Text = ord1.TotalCost

    End Sub
End Class
```

You can then create more than one order stored on the form using a list:

```
Dim CustomerOrders as List<Of Order>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create multiple instances of a form and show them non-morally. Whether this is the best design is another discussion.
The non-modal forms would all be visible and can be 'owned' by a main form.

Try something like this:

```
Dim firstInstance As New YourForm()
Dim secondInstance As New YourForm()

firstInstance.Show() 'Not ShowDialog()
secondInstance.Show(myParent) 'Optional parent form parameter
```

You'll need to watch the scope of your form instances as the forms will be closed if the variables go out of scope.

This may not be the ultimate solution, but it's something you can try on the way to finding the optimal approach.

Considering the latest comment:

The problem is not clear. Do you want to create multiple forms, one form per order? Or do you want one form that can show multiple orders?

My solution will allow you to show multiple forms while the other answer posted suggests a neat solution to creating one form with multiple orders.

Personally, I would create a single form that shows multiple orders, ListView maybe, that provides some way of viewing/editing each order's details and then allowing the orders to be submitted in a batch. It's more complex but would be more usable, IMHO.

Comment: Non-modally is very different to non-morally!

Comment: Also consider MDI style interface.

Comment: Some would argue that modality is immoral. Does that count?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe creating an array or using variables would work? The idea is to store information until it can be recalled. How would we create a variable to store items until the final purchase? Would procedure level variables work?